# How to avoid output from called script within wrapper

Tags: bash

I have written a wrapper in `bash`, which calls other shell scripts. However, I need to print only the output from the wrapper, avoiding the output from called scripts, which I am basically logging into a log file.

**Elaborating…..**

Basically I am using a function as

```
start_logging ${LOGFILE}
{
Funtion1
Funtion2
} 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
```

Where start logging is define as:- (I could only understand this function partially)

```
 start_logging()
{
## usage: start_logging
## start a new log or append to existing log file
declare -i rc=0
    if [ ! "${LOGFILE}" ];then
    ## display error and bail
   fi
local TIME_STAMP=$(date +%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S)
## open ${LOGFILE} or append to existing ${LOGFILE} with timestamp and actual command line
if [ ${DRY_RUN} ]; then
    echo "DRY_RUN set..."
    echo "${TIME_STAMP} Starting $(basename ${0}) run: '${0} ${ORIG_ARGS}'"  { I}
    echo "DRY_RUN set..."
    echo "Please ignore \"No such file or directory\" from tee..."
else
    echo "${TIME_STAMP} Starting $(basename ${0}) run: '${0} ${ORIG_ARGS}'"
    echo "${TIME_STAMP} Starting $(basename ${0}) run: '${0} ${ORIG_ARGS}'"
fi
return ${rc}
}
```

LOGFILE is defined in the wrapper as

```
{
TMPDIR  ="$/tmp" 
LOGFILE="${TMPDIR}/${$}/${BASENAME%.*}.log
}
```

Now when its calling funtion1, funtion2 which basically calls other bash scripts its logging all the output in the file .i.e. { TMPDIR}/${$}/${BASENAME%.*}.log } as well as on the bash terminal.

I wanted that it should only echo what I have written in the wrapper on to the bash terminal and rest should be recorded in the log.

PleaseNote:- the called scripts from wrapper have echo function within but I don’t wanted that there output should be displayed on the terminal

Is it possible to achieve....

Comment: You will get answers proportional to your question. If you provide more details, will get more detailed answer. For example, if you already logging subsequent scripts output, how they comes into stdout?

Answer (score 4):

You need to redirect both stdout + stderr of your called scripts into your logfile.

```
./your_other_script.sh 2&>1 >> /var/log/mylogfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You get output to the terminal, because of `tee`. So you can:

```
start_logging ${LOGFILE}
{
Funtion1
Funtion2
} 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE} >/dev/null
                           ^^^^^^^^^^ - redirect the output from a tee to /dev/null
```

or simply remove the `tee` and all logs redirect only into the file

```
start_logging ${LOGFILE}
{
Funtion1
Funtion2
} 2>&1 >${LOGFILE}
```

or for bigger parts of script, enclose the part into `(` `)` pair, will executed in a subshell and redirect the output to `/dev/null`, so:

```
(
start_logging ${LOGFILE}
{
Funtion1
Funtion2
} 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
) >/dev/null
```